# Why aren't direct sold campaigns (with admobs) visible in my app?

Tags: admob

I want to display a "Direct sold campaigns" by Admobs in my App.

- I have made a banner location in my app using the basic code. It shows (i think html5 banners) but no 320x50 banners or other format.
- I have made a Direct sold campaign with 100000 views in a month (to force it) with a 320x50 banner and a text banner.
- Both aren't visible in de app after 3 days.
- I also tried to force the banner format of 320x50 with this code in the app, but this didn't help either.

  Code used : let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 320, height: 50))
- There are no troubles with my admob account.

None of those steps help, I feel like i'm missing something.

Comment: Did you try with image (.png)? For about 2 weeks now the HTML5 banner seems not to be deserved anymore in our apps...